# print user name after successful login in angular8 application

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular8, mean-stack

i want to display my user name after a successful login. As i am working with the login token and my login logic is separately written and not in my auth file , so i will be including all my required files, for a better understanding

the following is the login component file

```
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
    return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched || isSubmitted));
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})



export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  mode: ProgressBarMode = 'indeterminate';
  value = 50;
  bufferValue = 75;
  loading:boolean=false;


  matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();


  loginForm = new FormGroup({
    email: new FormControl('', [Validators.email, Validators.required ]),
    password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.min(3) ])
  })
  get email() { return this.loginForm.get('email'); }
  get password() { return this.loginForm.get('password'); }

  errorMail = '';

  getErrorMessage(emailInput:HTMLInputElement) {
    const mail=/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@meltwater\.com/;
     if(!emailInput.value.match(mail)){
      this.errorMail='Email or password are not valid'
    }
    else{
      this.loading=true;
    }
  }



  constructor(
    private loginService: LoginService,
    private saveUserData:AuthService,
     private router: Router,
     private cookie:CookieService) { }

     userDisplayName = ''
  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
  rememberMe(e){
    if(e.target.checked){
      this.cookie.set('value',this.loginForm.value);
    }
  }

  onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log('value',this.loginForm.value)

    if(this.errorMail.length === 0) {
      this.loginService.login(this.loginForm.value).subscribe((res:any) => {
        console.log('login response', res)
        if(res.auth.success === true) {
          localStorage.setItem('auth', JSON.stringify(res.auth))
          this.loginService.loggedIn$.next(res.auth)
          this.saveUserData.saveAuthData(res)
          sessionStorage.setItem('loggedUser', res.Username);
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/search/list')
        } else {
        this.errorMail='Email or password is not valid'
        }
      })
    }
  }
  // returnUserName(){
  //   return this.userDisplayName = sessionStorage.getItem('loggedUser');

  // }

}
```

the following is the login service file

```
export class LoginService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  loggedIn$ = new BehaviorSubject(null)


  login(creds) {
    console.log('creds',creds)
   return this.http.post<LoginResponse>('https://backend.url/login', {creds})
  }
}
```

this is my auth service file , probably its not needed i suppose

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class AuthService {
  private isAuthenticated = false;
  private token: string;
  private email: string;
  private authStatusListener = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {}

  getToken() {
    return this.token;
  }

  getIsAuth() {
    return this.isAuthenticated;
  }

  getAuthStatusListener() {
    return this.authStatusListener.asObservable();
  }

  public saveAuthData(token: string) {
    localStorage.setItem("token", token);

  }

  private clearAuthData() {
    localStorage.removeItem("token");

  }


  logout() {

    // this.token = null;
    this.clearAuthData();
    this.router.navigate(["/"]);
  }


  autoAuthUser() {
    const authInformation = this.getAuthData();

      this.token = authInformation.token;
      this.isAuthenticated = true;

      this.authStatusListener.next(true);

  }

  private getAuthData() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    if (!token ) {
      return;
    }
    return {
      token: token
    }
  }

 userDetails(){
  sessionStorage.setItem('loggedUser', .email);
 }

}
```

this is where i want to display my user name : the header

following is the header component

```
import { AuthService } from './../../auth/auth.service';
import { LoginComponent } from './../../login/login.component';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  public userIsAuthenticated;
  public userName = '';


  constructor(public authService: AuthService,public router:Router, public user:LoginComponent) { }


  onLogout(){
    this.authService.logout();
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userName = this.user.returnUserName() ;
  }




}
```

this is throwing me error , probably bcz login component is been imported , i am not so sure about why the error is occuring

Comment: please share what error are you facing

Comment: Can you please attach the error text that you are getting? You are trying to inject the LoginComponent into the HeaderComponent. That is not the way you should be dealing with this. In Angular, use a Service (@Injectible) between the two components.

Comment: i have moved my code to auth service now and it is not throwing any error now but still i am not able to display the user name , the user name field says undefined

Comment: @AndreasLorenzen

Answer (score 0):

You can not inject Component as service, use  `@ViewChild(LoginComponent)` instead, but this will not solve the problem.

To get username try moving that method in `AuthService`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i moved my code to auth , but that is also not giving me result